# Where should we direct our marketing?

Tags: discussion, marketing

Certainly there are a lot of websites and communities where we can promote our SE and hope to gain more users from. Can you suggest such websites and communities here, and possibly help spreading the word about this SE?

Answer (score 4):

[Langauge Log](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/) has a fairly large readership, but a plug for the site there might open the floodgates to trolls.

Comment: It's hard to open the gates and not let trolls in no matter what, sooner or later we will have to deal with trolls unless we actively try **not** to expand our readership, which can hardly be good.

Answer (score 3):

My favourite language related site is [languagehat](http://languagehat.com)

Comment: how can we gain some attention there? Do you know how to write the blogger?

Comment: The guy who runs it is pretty amiable if you send him an email but he might not like purely plugging a site. Best is to get him to play with it and if he likes it he will surely blog about it: languagehat@gmail.com

Comment: How should I address him? Dear Language Hat blogger doesn't sound right :))

Comment: On the site everybody calls him Hat (-:

Comment: Make sure you appeal to him to stop by and help answer some questions!

Answer (score 3):

I'll be promoting the site to my alma mater, I've already pushed it on some other linguistics-heavy places I frequent.

Who'll do the linguist list?

Comment: I don't know, but someone should.  Our commitment on Area 51 shot up from ~75% (IIRC) to 100% basically overnight after the proposal was advertised there.

Comment: @Aaron Who announced it there the last time?

Comment: Taylor Smith did - that's how I found it! Perhaps a follow up post would be good, especially now it's open access and there's a good bulk of posts.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics

Someone mentioned us there last time we were announced on Linguist List (when we still needed commitments to launch), but I don't think I've seen a mention lately.

Comment: I've posted there the 2 questions which I'm "taking care" of: http://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/llw8z/which_languages_have_a_marker_of_the_comparative/, http://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/llwpv/which_languages_have_two_coexisting_markers_of/. (As well as a followup to the original message with these question in *mosling*, a mailing list for linguists, in Russian.)